# Translating content in filesystem for a Plone product

Tags: python, internationalization, plone, zope

I'm trying to get certain strings in a .py file translated, using the i18n machinery.  Translating .pt files is not a problem, but whenever I try to translate using _('Something') in Python code on the filesystem, it always gives English text (which is the default) instead of the Norwegian text that should be there.  So I can see output from python code in English, while other Page Templates bits are correctly translated.

Is there a how-to or something similar for this?

Answer (score 3):

if you are seeking for how-tos you should probably read these docs:

- http://plone.org/documentation/kb/i18n-for-developers
- http://readthedocs.org/docs/collective-docs/en/latest/i18n/localization.html

Bye,
Giacomo

Comment: The first hyperlink still works (as of now), but the readthedocs link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Is the domain name used for `_('Something')` the same as what you use in the Norwegian .po file that has the translation?  They should be the same, so do not use 'plone' in one case and 'my.domain' in the other.

Also, the call to the underscore function does not in itself translate the string; it only creates a string that can be translated.  If this string ends up on its own directly in a template, you should add `i18n:translate=""` to that tag, probably with a matching i18n:domain.

Otherwise you should manually call the `translate` method, as in http://readthedocs.org/docs/collective-docs/en/latest/i18n/localization.html#manually-translated-message-ids. Read the [Plone 4 migration guide](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-3-x-to-4.0/updating-add-on-products-for-plone-4.0/manual-calls-to-translate) for some differences between Plone 3 and 4 that might bite you here.

Comment: This worked well, was exactly the help I needed.  Don't have enough reputation to vote you up yet though.

Answer (score 3):

be aware that _() does not translate the text at call, but returns a Message object which will be translated when rendered in a template.

That means:

1. do not concat Message objects. `"text %s" % _('translation')` will not work, as well as `"text" + _('translation')`
2. if you do not send the text to the browser through a template, it may not be translated. for example if you generate a email you need to translate the Message object manually